# offline install

Tags: ros, debian, ros-fuerte, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I install a ROS(Fuerte) in a debian system, I do have the 8 ISOs can support the package that has to be installed before installing rosinstall rospkg rosdep, but I do not know how to install ROS itself. Who can help me? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53268/offline-install/) by [Slittery](https://answers.ros.org/users/4039/slittery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this answer can help you:

http://answers.ros.org/question/10201/ros-offline-install/

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1